# where should I set METEOR_DISABLE_OPTIMISTIC_CACHING

Tags: performance, meteor, reaction-commerce

I am totally new to Meteor. I am trying to run [Reaction Commerce](https://reactioncommerce.com/) on my local machine. I found someone pointed that set `METEOR_DISABLE_OPTIMISTIC_CACHING = 1` can speed up the meteor loading time. However, I don't know how to set this thing up on Window 10.

Does anyone know about this?

Answer (score 1):

`METEOR_DISABLE_OPTIMISTIC_CACHING` is an environment variable.

You can set it in three ways:

1. system-wide in control panel
2. for a specific shell by using `SET METEOR_DISABLE_OPTIMISTIC_CACHING=1` in a command prompt before running meteor. Easiest to use in a `.bat` file
3. in an npm script using the `cross-env` package

I recommend using `cross-env`. First `meteor npm install --save cross-env`

Then add a start script to `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "cross-env METEOR_DISABLE_OPTIMISTIC_CACHING=1 meteor run"
}
```

now when you run `npm start` it will set the environment variable just for that one running instance of meteor

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried the second and the third way. But none of them work for me. I keep getting "undefined" in my console. I go into the meteor folder. Then, I typed `SET METEOR_DISABLE_OPTIMISTIC_CACHING=1`. In my main.js, I used `console.log(process.env.METEOR_DISABLE_OPTIMISTIC_CACHING);` to log the result. But eventually, I got "undefined". I am not sure if there were anything wrong with my meteor installation. Do you have any idea about this?